# Send HTTP notifications with query params with Spring web client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to send http notifications with query params with Spring web client. I tried this:

```
WebClient client;

public Mono<Response> execute(String url) {

        MultiValueMap map = new MultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("some_key", "some_value");

        return client.post().uri(builder -> builder
                .host("http://www.test.com/notification")
                .queryParams(map).build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
    }
```

But I have several issues:
When I try to use MultiValueMap I get error `Cannot instantiate the type MultiValueMap`

Also how I can get the notification result? I don't want to send any payload or get any payload. I only want to get OK for response.

**EDIT:**

```
public Mono<String> execute(String url) {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("some_key", "some_value");

        return client.post().uri(builder -> builder
                .queryParams(map).build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
```

Comment: MultiValueMap is an interface, try the concrete class LinkedMultiValueMap. If you want the response try exchange() over retrieve(), which gives you a response object clientResponse.getStatusCode().

Answer (score 1):

### MultiValueMap

[MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) is an interface from `org.springframework.util`

You are trying to instantiate it the following way:

```
MultiValueMap map = new MultiValueMap<>();
```

This won't work as you need to provide an implementation of the interface. If you really want to instantiate it this way then maybe try using one of the implementations of the `MultiValueMap`, like [LinkedMultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html).

### OK for response

If you are only interested in the result (i.e. the status code) of the request, you could try to do the following:

```
client.post().uri(builder -> builder
    .host("http://www.test.com/notification")
    .queryParams(map).build())
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .exchange()
    .map(ClientResponse::statusCode);
```

The last call to `map(...)` will return an instance of `Mono<HttpStatus>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find method statusCode()? Can you paste code example please to show what do you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a mistake on my side. Please, see my updated answer.